# What's the correct way to add references in .net core -- assembly, or nuget?

Tags: .net-core

Issue:
I'm referencing the IConfiguration interface in a .net core 2.1 library that will run in a linux docker container

Visual Studio 2019 automatically offers to add an assembly reference for me.  If I accept, it references the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll that is in my program files directory.

However, I see that there is also a nuget packager for this dll online.

It's easy to say "just trust visual studio", but I've run into issues before with the .net framework where VS (or resharper) will try to add an assembly reference when the assembly it wants to reference is really part of a package that needs to be added.

I'm a long-timer with .net, just picking up .net core.  What's the correct convention in this case?

Comment: Paste the actual project file as part of the question please.

Comment: I would use nuget as it’s not guaranteed that all machines will have the program files folder in the same location. Plus it is easier to ensure all projects have the same version when using nuget rather than assembly references.

Answer (score 3):

.NET Core is designed with package references as standard way to reference dependencies. There are several reasons for that design choice, however, the primary one is to allow to run code on multiple OS and arch targets. Therefore, recommended way of creating dependencies is by using package references. It will allow to fetch packages which are relevant for given OS and CPU combination.

For example, you could target with you build Windows, Linux and macOS and for Linux and Windows x64 and arm64 architectures while for macOS x64 architecture. Project referencing packages will pick for a given combination of operating system and processor architecture appropriate packages i.e. in case of SQLite it would be win-x64, win-arm64, linux-x64, linux-arm64, macOS-x64 package versions. The same is true for .NET Core packages and runtimes which would be chosen based on combination of target platform and target architecture. The general concept of handling all these combinations is abstracted by Target Framework Moniker which besides of handling OS and architecture information allows to handle version dependency information as well.

All the above is a fundamental concept for understanding versioning and OS/architecture dependency handling in .NET Core which is implemented in it's project system as well. In the case as yours you should always choose nuget package instead of assembly reference, despite suggestion made by Visual Studio which in general not always works correctly. To verify this one can check number of issues which were closed or are still open in dotent/project-system repository on github where .NET Core project system used by Visual Studio lives.

Finally, despite that referencing pure IL assemblies will work it is not future proof, since any change in the dependency which makes it platform or architecture specific (i.e. architecture specific optimizations with .NET Core HW intrinsic) would break your project.